# Problem with retrieving the value of item in list/dictionary of objects in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to put string variables into list/dictionary in python3.7 and trying to retrieve them later for use.

I know that I can create a dictionary like:

```
string_dict1 = {"A":"A", "B":"B", "C":"C", "D":"D", "E":"E", "F":"F"}
```

and then retrieve the values, but it is not I want in this specific case.

Here is the code:

```py
A = ""
B = "ABD"
C = ""
D = "sddd"
E = ""
F = "dsas"


string_dict = {A:"A", B:"B", C:"C", D:"D", E:"E", F:"F"}
string_list = [A,B,C,D,E,F]
for key,val in string_dict.items():
    if key == "":
        print(val)


for item in string_list:
    if item == "":
        print(string_list.index(item))
```

The result I got is:

```
E
0
0
0
```

And the result I want is:

```
A
C
E
0
2
4
```

Comment: You can't have multiple dictionary keys with same name, in this case "". If you have multiple same named keys in you dict python will only leave the last one.

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary when you don't need a dictionary?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the reply. I have a list of Tkinter comboboxes and I want to check if the comboboxes in the list are empty. Say if ComboA.get() == "", then add ("ComboA is empty") to an Errorlist, then put out the Errorlist at last. Is there a better way to do it instead of the dictionary/list?

Comment: @Cyber If dictionary cannot able to do that. How about the list? Is there a way I can go through the list with some objects that equal to empty and find the positions of these objects? It seems that python did find all the empty objects but it prints out wrong index.

Answer (score 1):

If you print `string_dict` you notice the problem:

```
string_dict = {A:"A", B:"B", C:"C", D:"D", E:"E", F:"F"}
print(string_dict)
# output: {'': 'E', 'ABD': 'B', 'sddd': 'D', 'dsas': 'F'}
```

It contains a single entry with the value `""`.
This is because you are associating multiple values ​​to the same key, and this is not possible in python, so only the last assignment is valid (in this case `E:"E"`).

If you want to associate multiple values ​​with the same key, you could associate a list:

```
string_dict = {A:["A","C","E"], B:"B", D:"D", F:"F"}
```

Regarding the list of strings `string_list`, you get 0 since the method `.index(item)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `item` in the list. In your case 0. For example, if you change the list `[A,B,C,D,E,F]` to `[B,B,C,D,E,F]`. Your code will print `2`.

If you want to print the index of the empty string in your list:

```
for index, value in enumerate(string_list):
    if value == '':
        print(index)
```

Or in a more elegant way you can use a list comprehension:

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(string_list) if x=='']
```

Comment: You only explained half his question -- not why he is printing 3 zeroes.

Comment: Have I clarified your doubts?

Comment: If you are talking to me, you answered his question but I never had any doubts. By the way your `for` loop and your `list comprehension` are not equivalent in the sense that one prints numbers and the other one does not but does create a list that is discarded. Now, you could have said: `[print(i) for i,x in enumerate(string_list) if x=='']`, a bit weird-looking perhaps. There you would have been creating a list of `None` values (the return code from `print`) just for the side effect.That is to say, you could have, but I wouldn't. But some might say it's faster.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't think there's a way to get what you want from a dictionary because of how they work. You can print your dictionary and see that it looks like this:

```
{'': 'E', 'ABD': 'B', 'sddd': 'D', 'dsas': 'F'}
```

What happened here is A was overwritten by C and then E.

But I played around with the list and here's how I got the last three digits right:

```
for item in string_list:
    if item != '':
        print(string_list.index(item) - 1)
```

This prints:

```
0
2
4
```

Comment: Your for-loop doesn't make much sense to me. Try to see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57861633/9302488).